# Show Or Hide Div Based On CSS Class

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am trying to show or hide a div called "contact-form" on website based on another divs a css class, which is connected to whether a product is in or out of stock.

It needs to show the div if the class is "in-stock", and hide if it's class is "out-of-stock"

any ideas? struggling to figure it out!

```
<div id="contact-form"></div>

<p class="stock in-stock"></p> <!-- if product is in stock this shows-->

<p class="stock out-of-stock"></p> <!-- if out of stock this show-->

<script>

    if ('p.in-stock') {
        ('#contact-form').show();   
    }
    else {
        ('#contact-form').hide();
    }

</script>
```

Website is here - http://trent-art.co.uk/shop/barnes-david-still-life-of-flowers/ - out of stock product which needs the "submit best offer" button hiding if out of stock.

Comment: Add your `HTML` code also

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: jQuery makes this easy.

Comment: this should help you http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp it shows you on to hide/reveal by click, you can then adapt it to your needs

Comment: Show/Hide the div, or the `<p>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't tag your question with `jQuery`, here is a vanilla JS alternative:

```
var formDiv = document.getElementById("contact-form");
var stockPara = document.getElementsByClassName("stock");
var sStockClass = stockPara[0].className;
formDiv.style.display = (sStockClass.indexOf("in-stock") < 0) ? "none" : "block";
```

This code could be shortened into fewer lines (technically, you could do it in one), but I left it broken up for clarity.  The "consolidated" version would be:

```
document.getElementById("contact-form").style.display =
    (document.getElementsByClassName("stock")[0].className.indexOf("in-stock") < 0) ?
    "none" : "block";
```

If you're not familiar with ternary operators, that is what I used in the last line . . . it's basically a one-condition, two-option, one-line, `if` statement.  The code says, "if 'in-stock' is in the `sStockName` string value, then assign 'block' as the `display` value, otherwise, use 'none'"

More info on ternaries here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#contact-form').toggle($('p.stock').hasClass('in-stock'));
```

**OR**

```
if ($('p.stock').hasClass('in-stock')) {
    $('#contact-form').show();
} else {
    $('#contact-form').hide();
}
```

Comment: He didn't mention that he uses jQuery.

Comment: i have added this to my site and it didn't work
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() ({
    if ($('p.stock').hasClass('in-stock')) {$('#contact-form').show();
        } 
   else {
      $('#contact-form').hide();
       }
      });
 </script>

Comment: @cookney Make sure you've loaded `jQuery` before this, and all the elements used above are unique on the page

Comment: @tushar sorry still  not working, can see my code right at bottom of the page on http://trent-art.co.uk/shop/barnes-david-still-life-of-flowers/ - best offer button remains

Answer (score 1):

in pure Js it's:

```
var p= document.querySelector("p")

 if (p.className.match(/\bin-stock\b/)) {
document.querySelector("#contact-form").style.display = 'block';
}else{
document.querySelector("#contact-form").style.display = 'none';
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/8g6a6rpg/)

[**fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/8g6a6rpg/1/) ---the one with display block---

Comment: @cookney strange; in my example it's working.. look at fiddle

Answer (score 0):

if there is 1 contact form per product then put div of contact form inside product and hide with css :

```
.in-stock + .showOrHide
{
    display:block;
}

.sold + .showOrHide
{
    display:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o379yqy5/1/

Comment: i want to hide the contact form if the product is out of stock, so the above example doesnt work.

Comment: Then your example is not clear because there is 1 form but 2 products in your example ... 1 in-stock and 1 out-of-stock, what should the result be for your example ? Is there a contact form per product ? or is there only 1 product and 1 contact form normally ?